# Force release an autorelease object

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

Can I force an Autorelase object by calling a release without autorelease pool like that:

```
NSString *myString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
[myString release];
```

Normally it's like that:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *myString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
[pool release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first sample will crash, since the string will get over-released. If you want to have control over the lifetime of your autoreleased objects, the correct approach is what your second sample does – create a local autorelease pool that you can drain when you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will crash because global auto release pool will try to release the object later. Results in malloc double free error

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
NSString *myString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Or this:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString *myString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
[pool release];
```

But not this:

```
NSString *myString = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
[myString release];
```